# canvas and DOM layering

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I am making a HTML5 game using `melonJS` engine... which makes use of the canvas (imports and uses Tiled TMX maps)

I have created a puzzle using DOM elements (which I found much easier than making the puzzle in Tiled map editor). The player entity class (class that melonJS helps me draw to the canvas and animate) needs to be able to navigate the puzzle when it pops up...

Unfortunately, the DOM overlaps the player sprite since the puzzle sits apart from the DOM.

[SIMPLIFIED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrcjv4kf/1/)

To fix this:

- I thought I could adjust the player's z-index to be more than the DOM puzzle... but it still remains overlapped. Here, the player.z index and puzzle z index show that the `z-index` doesn't matter because they are on completely different layers... otherwise the player's `36` would clearly overlap the puzzle's `0`:

  ```
  var player = me.game.world.getChildByName("mainPlayer")[0];
  log(player.z);  //logs 36
  log($("#puzzle").css("z-index"));  //logs 0
  ```
- I figured I could add a secondary canvas, and:

  -- temporarily remove/hide the player's sprite (game.PlayerEntity) on the game canvas

  -- add a new player sprite to the top layer canvas

  -- give that player sprite focus/control - aka. bind the keys to that    new player object

But that seems like a lot of unnecessary work

**What I mean:**

[image]

Is there a way to draw a canvas element such that I can see the player sprite?

Comment: We need to see your HTML and CSS. Can you replicate it live?

Comment: @Shomz there is so much going on so it's tough for me to replicate it. Therefore I was looking for more of a highlevel strategy

Comment: I'm 100% sure this could be fixed with plain CSS, try not to overcomplicate it. I just need the basic markup and CSS, no need to recreate any of the game elements... blank canvas, no images, etc. I just need to see how you structured it.

Comment: @Shomz simplified fiddle added above. should capture the gist of what I'm doing... although I'm drawing sprites to the canvas, which is handled with the `melonJS` engine, so not sure if canvas element drawing is handled that way

Comment: It doesn't matter what you draw on canvas, it's just a DOM element that's covering the other one. It seems fine in your fiddle. Oh wait, you want the red square to appear OVER the puzzle element while the puzzle element is covering the rest of the canvas? That's not possible, you'll need another canvas for that.

Comment: @Shomz so you recommend those steps I listed above in the 2nd bullet point?

Comment: Sort of, you can simply draw the player on the top canvas instead of the main one, and problem solved. Just modify your player draw function so you can pass in the alternate canvas/context.